# images padding when converting html to pdf using itextpdf and XMLWorker

Tags: itextpdf, xmlworker

I am using  XMLWorker 5.5.3 and itextpdf 5.5.3 to convert html to pdf.
my html contain table with cells that conatin images. 
i.e. part of my code :

[image]

my problem is that some cells add padding > 0 so the td that contain the image is bigger than it should be. 
Is there a way to define style for images so the will not have padding and margin ? 
I am looking at [css Demo of Itextpdf](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm) and not finding a solution , any help/trick /ideas will help .
thanks
Tami

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: 
when  I create the table I define columns width :

```
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(vColWidth.length);
 table.setWidthPercentage(100);
 table.setWidths(vColWidth);
```

when creating the Image object I define :

```
RegularImg = Image.getInstance(imgsrc); 
RegularImg.setSpacingAfter(0);
RegularImg.setSpacingBefore(0);
```

when defining the td :

```
cell = new PdfPCell(RegularImg);
if(colSpan!="") 
    cell.setColspan(Integer.parseInt(colSpan));
if(rowSpan!= "") 
    cell.setRowspan(Integer.parseInt(rowSpan));
if(cellHight!="") 
    cell.setFixedHeight(Float.parseFloat(cellHight));

table.addCell(cell);
```

this solutions works o.k. if the table is not so big or complicated with the colSpan , rowSpan .
In complicated cases I advise people to convert the table of pictures as a Canvas , not using a table. just place each Image in the specific place in the doc . (the performance are much faster.